# Python sqlalchemy отфильтровать записи в relationship

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть две таблицы Group  и User.  Юзеры могут находится в нескольких группах одновременно.

```
user_has_group = db.Table("user_has_group",
                          db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id")),
                          db.Column("group_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("group.id"))
                          )
```

**Group**

```
class Group(db.Model):
       """ Group model """
       __tablename__ = "group"
       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
       project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("project.id"), nullable=True)
       project = db.relationship("Project", foreign_keys=[project_id])
       active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True, index=True)
       name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
```

**User**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    """ User model """
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)   
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, index=True)
    email_confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)    
    password = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=True)
    groups = db.relationship("Group", secondary=user_has_group, lazy="dynamic",
                     backref=db.backref("users", lazy="dynamic"))
```

Есть **код**, который должен для каждой группы выводит юзеров.

```
groups = Group.query.all()
for group in groups:
    users = User.query.filter(group in User.groups).all()
```

**Но код не работает.**

Помогите, пожалуйста, как вывести юзеров для каждой из группы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
groups = Group.query.all()
for group in groups:
    users = group.users
```